# View page source from sites in browser's history?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

Is it possible to view the page source or parts of the source from web pages that have been viewed in the past (e.g., a week ago)? This assumes no extensions or plugins have been added to the browser.

Comment: This would be a security hole. You don't have access to the browser history or cache.

Comment: @MikeW, what about the browser owner (not third party)? I should have made this more clear. Meaning, does Chrome allow the ability to view source/cache of sites I've visited in the past?